# Cannot edit kendo grid after deploy the project on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

[image]I have a gird, that works normally while I'm working locally, but when I deploy the code on a server I cannot edit anymore the grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BussinessUnitDto>()
    .Name("FunctionsGrid")                 
    .AutoBind(true)
    .Scrollable() 
    .ToolBar(toolBar =>
    {
        toolBar.Create();
        toolBar.Save();
    })  
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(false))
    .DataSource(ds=>ds.Ajax().Batch(true).ServerOperation(false)                                   
    .Read("GetDeliveryUnits","DeliveryUnits")
    .Create("Editing_Create", "DeliveryUnits")
    .Update("Editing_Update", "DeliveryUnits")
    .Destroy("Editing_Destroy", "DeliveryUnits")
    .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.UnitID);
        })
    )                          
    .Columns(c =>
    {
        c.Bound(e => e.UnitName);
        c.Command(com => com.Destroy());
    }
))
```

If I'm looking with FireBug for example, I see that the input for editing cell is not created.
Does anyone know why this behaviour?

Thank you :)

Comment: can you explain what you mean cannot edit the grid..?? `1.you see no edit button  2. you click the button update the data in row and hit update button and nothing gets saved..?? 3. which browser version you are using..???

Comment: Hey, I tried to edit my answer and post an image. The idea is that when I'm trying to click in one cell to edit it, the content of that cell disappear.

Comment: I'm using FireFox as browser

Comment: post your server side code as well..